# JavaScript RegEx for matching a string having length between 1 to 5 characters and should not start and end with space

Tags: javascript, regex

Need help in creating a JavaScript RegEx for matching a string having length between 1 to 5 characters and should not start and end with space. But it can have spaces in between.

I can come up with following

```
/(^\S\w*){1,5}/
```

But it is allowing string of length greater than 5 characters and it is also allowing string with trailing space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m   m` (three spaces between the m’s) is valid and you you want to allow any non-whitespace characters (`\S`), not just word characters (`\w`), you can restate your requirements as:

- One non-whitespace character, optionally followed by:

  - Zero to three characters of any kind
  - One non-whitespace character

(The key is to group those last two.)

That gives us:

```
^\S(?:.{0,3}\S)?$
```

[Try it out.](https://regex101.com/r/fGcK5D/1) (Thanks to RobC for [the original examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744260/javascript-regex-for-matching-a-string-having-length-between-1-to-5-characters-a#comment90450526_51745069), which I expanded a bit.)

If you want to match only word characters, you can instead say:

```
^\w(?:[\s\w]{0,3}\w)?$
```

[Try it out.](https://regex101.com/r/JaKOm6/2)